# PINS Demat account for NRI

Tags: india, trading, non-resident

I learned from other questions on this forum that an NRI has the option to invest in individual stocks in India through a PINS Demat account. Is this a recent development? I was told by my broker in the past that an NRI does not have the option to invest in individual stocks in India, but can trade only derivatives, and invest in mutual funds.